# How to generate random Uint32 Go

Tags: go

I need to generate random Uint32 type, I know how to do in int but because of high numbers cause an overflow.

is it possible to generate random Uint32 in min and max range?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter that you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the standard library:

https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Uint32

To force it within a range, you can use modulu and plus

Example:

```
func randU32(min, max uint32) uint32 {
    var a = rand.Uint32()
    a %= (max - min)
    a += min
    return a
}
```

on playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/AlMfjJOTvtv

Comment: Thanks a lot, so you can write an example?

Comment: sure, added an example